# docker swarm - file.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

When I run the docker.yaml file I get an error :
failed to create service some=stack_busybox: Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = name must be valid as a DNS name component.
`I use command docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker.yml some=stack`. How can I solve the problems? I try to create global servie use command `docker service create busybox`, but it doesn't help.

My docker.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
   busybox:
   image: busybox
     networks:
       - net
   test:
      networks:
       - testing
       - net
networks:
    testing:
        external: true
    net:
        external: true
```

Comment: Is there more output than just that error message?  Can you fix the example here to be correct (at least the `busybox` `image:` needs to be indented one step more, and `test` needs at `image:` itself)?

Comment: It doesn't help. There aren't any more error messages, only `Creating service some=stack_busybox
failed to create service some=stack_busybox: Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = name must be valid as a DNS name component
`

Comment: its not even worth proceeding until you address @DavidMaze and show a vagely valid compose file.